# WCF Silverlight crossdomain problem

Tags: silverlight, wcf, cross-domain

I have several WCF services.
When I check them on the server (example: ServiceTest.svc?wsdl), than I see an xml file with info about the wcf service. So the services works fine.

I have a Silverlight application on a different server.
I get the 'famous' crossdomain error.
When I place a clientaccesspolicy.xml in the directory with the WCF services, the problem remains.

Is it possible that with shared hosting, the security isn't high/low enough?

thanks,

Filip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML file must be placed in the root of the domain. Usually you have to put them into the inetpub/wwwroot folder, instead of into the folder with the WCF services.

Depending on how your provider implemented the shared hosting, I'm afraid you'll have to ask them to support cross domain access and put the XML files into the root.

I am not sure but I think it also could work to register your own domain that points to the folder you want to use as root, and put the XML files there. The clients must then use the server URLs with your registered domain of course.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best tools for issues like this is [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com)(or some other web debugging proxy).  Looking at the network calls, you can see the address where the browser is looking for the clientaccesspolicy.xml file and then make sure you drop the file at that location.  If you're not seeing this call or you're seeing it and the file is already there, you can move on to other issues (a bug in the webservice or the calling code).